# My SQL query not retrieving all the data from the database

Tags: mysql

I have a table in my database with the name `contact`. It has the following columns: **name, mobile and twon**. The problem is that I'm trying to get all the `twon='Dubai'`, but when I execute my query it only retrieves 81000 rows but the total was 130000. The other remaining rows are not appearing in my query.

My Query:

```
SELECT * FROM `contact` WHERE `twon` = 'Dubai'
```

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong or help me to access all the data from table?

Comment: how about `trim(twon) = 'Dubai'` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`=` will fetch the record only if the column value is **exactly** 'dubai'.

Try with `LIKE`,`TRIM` and `LOWER`:

```
SELECT * FROM `contact` WHERE LOWER(TRIM(`twon`)) LIKE '%dubai%'
```

This query will fetch the records if `twon` column contains the word 'dubai'.

Answer (score 1):

Different things could be wrong.
If you post examples of rows that should be returned, it would help us.

- Case Sensitivity

If case sensitivity is a problem (e.g. 'dubai' or 'DUBAI' are not returned), you can use the [LOWER](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_lower) function

```
SELECT * FROM `contact` WHERE LOWER(`twon`) = 'dubai'
```

- Extra blanks

In some cases, extra blanks in the column content would fail, for instance '  Dubai' and ' Dubai  '. You can use the [TRIM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim) function to get rid of trailing and leading blanks.

```
SELECT * FROM `contact` WHERE TRIM(`twon`) = 'Dubai'
```

- Combination

Combining the two will work, too.

```
SELECT * FROM `contact` WHERE LOWER(TRIM(`twon`)) = 'dubai'
```